# Bash: read line by line from two variables

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to read line by line from two bash variables.
Assume that we have:

```
   A= 1
      2
      3
      4
   B= 5
      6
      7
      8
```

the desired output would be:

```
1 versus 5
2 versus 6
3 versus 7
4 versus 8
```

I write the following lines:

```
while read a && read -u 3 b; do
echo "$a versus $b"
done <"$A" 3< `echo "$B"`
```

but it doesn't work. I guess that the problem is when redirecting the value of B. I have also tried:

```
done <"$A" 3<<< `echo "$B"`
done <"$A" 3< "$B"
done <"$A" 3< (cat "$B")
```

but it still does not work.

Comment: `paste ina.txt inb.txt | sed 's/\s\+/ versus /g'`

Comment: I tried with paste but it won`t work fine for what I have to do. Actually, what I`ve described above is only a short example, the real values will be more complicated, every line for each file might contain space and other separators. Anyway, thank you for your reply !

Comment: then post the real files, and well adjust above paste command

Comment: How have you set up the variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read from two variables, you'll need process substitution.

```
while read a && read -u 3 b; do
    echo "$a versus $b"
done < <( printf "%s\n" "$A") 3< <(printf "%s\n" "$B")
```

The output of each `printf` looks like a file to `bash`, so all the regular input redirections can be used.

Comment: why you use `printf "%s\n"` as that's the same than `echo`?

Comment: Force of habit. `echo` varies from shell to shell, so I use `printf` for consistency.

Comment: @lucian.marcuta You might consider using Gunstick's answer instead. I probably would have suggested `3<<<` if I'd realized it was a legal construct.

Answer (score 3):

As you guessed, you had the input redirections wrong. My first trial was to use a file based approach and substitute the variables as files with <(...) and then redirect that.

```
while read a && read -u 3 b
do
  echo "$a versus $b"
done < <(echo "$A") 3< <(echo "$B")
```

Then I modified to use the <<< operator like this

```
while read a && read -u 3 b
do
  echo "$a versus $b"
done <<<"$A" 3<<<"$B"
1 versus 5
2 versus 6
3 versus 7
4 versus 8
```

Comment: The example with `<<<` does not work for two streams.

Comment: Whoops! Why did I not copy/paste? the second <<< should be 3<<<

Comment: Actually, I was trying to point out that `3<<<` wouldn't work, but apparently it does (it just isn't documented in the man page).

Answer (score 1):

Using paste hack

```
A=1$'\n'2$'\n'3$'\n'4
B=5$'\n'6$'\n'7$'\n'8

paste -d " versus " <(echo "$A") /dev/null{,,,,,,} <(echo "$B")

1 versus 5
2 versus 6
3 versus 7
4 versus 8
```

Comment: No need to open and close the quotes for each newline; `A=$'1\n2\n3\n4'` works the same.